# Ruby devise gem with bcrypt-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, bcrypt

I am in the process of creating a webapp, and was wondering is there a way to incorporate bcrypt with devise, so the password encryption is with bcrypt. If so how? If not is there a make devise more secure, or should I just build the user/password authentication from scratch?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: devise uses bcrypt by default. [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb)

Comment: Really, I did not now cool thanks